# How to add a file to BBEdit Project folders

Tags: project, bbedit

[image]

I have these two folders in a BBEdit project. When I drag one of the files into the folder, the file is not added to the folder? How do I add a file to the folder in a project?

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the file to the folder in the Finder, it will be updated in the project. Here is what you do according to the BBEdit manual:

> To add files or folders to a project, drag them from the Finder into
> the project window, or click the Add button. When you click Add,
> BBEdit presents the Open dialog in which you can choose one or more
> files and folders to add. The files and folders you select will be
> added directly to the project’s file list, and you can drag them to
> reorganize their positions. You can also add a file by dragging its
> icon from a text window’s navigation bar or sidebar to the group
> window, or by dragging a file entry from any disk browser or results
> browser.